# i want to drop 2 rows in the dataframe if zero comes in the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

if 0 comes on odd index drop previous row as well as current row using pandas

example

```
column1    column2
a              1
b              0
c              2
b              3
e              7
f              0
```

output

```
column1    column2
c              2
b              3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is indexed starting from 0

```
# Rows with column2 = 0 and on odd index
idx = df[(df['column2'] == 0) & (df.index % 2 == 1)].index

# The rows above them
idx = idx.append(idx-1)

# A new dataframe with those rows removed
result = df.drop(idx)
```